# Unexpected token in Vue / HTML Markup

Tags: vue.js, syntax, components

[image: I knew that I am Vue beginner - but I did not expect to be puzzled by this]

Why is this token "unexpected"? What is the correct for of this declaration?

Comment: Try removing the spaces. `:articles="articles"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `v-bind:articles="articles"`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers and "try this" answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how they work and why they work.

Comment: Thank you parthjani7 - your suggestion is the correct answer - seeing it, I thought "of course" immediately!